# How to add 'Insert HTML Table' button to TinyMCE in admin?

Tags: wp-admin, tinymce

I am trying to figure out how to change the default buttons on the TinyMCE editor in the Wordpress admin. Specifically, I would like to provide an 'insert table' button. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) plugin. I almost never launch a site without it.